# Displaying labels only for desktop and for iPad only when landscape mode

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Using Foundation framework, I am trying to do 4 labels which will be only visible only desktop and for iPad only when landscape mode. So, the code I tried the following in the html form:

```html
<p class="show-for-landscape show-for-medium-up text-left degree-finder-label"> Sort by Degree Level</p>
```

And in the CSS, I tried to do:

```css
 .degree-finder-label {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: DINOTBold;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position:absolute;
    top: -20px;
}
```

But this is working only for some situations and if the screen sieze is like less than the iPad screen size, then only the first lable is coming and resto of them are completly missing. Am I doing something wrong or I have to add more classes to fix that issue.

Thanks

Comment: I am assuming that you have `@media-query` set for all of these? [Media Queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: thanks. i solved that. it was an issue with @media-query which was applied another sub-layout.